# Rails backend and React Frontend. Authentication, user is not persisting after refresh

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, authentication, session, cookies

I have a rails backend and react frontend. Login and logout is working just fine. My problem is when I refresh the page, I am getting logged out. I have session setup in my backend, so I'm not sure why my user is not persisting. I've set up my cors to allow the route too. Any help is appreciated.

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :users, only: [:index, :create] 
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get '/me', to: 'users#show'


  resources :players do
    resources :statistics
    resources :videos
    post 'upload_image', on: :member
  end

  resources :sports do
    resources :sport_media_videos
  end

  get 'cors-test', to: 'test#cors_test'
end
```

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:create, :show]

def create
  user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
  if user&.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    render json: user, status: :ok
  else
    render json: { error: 'Incorrect username or password, please try again' }, status: :unauthorized
  end
end

 def destroy
  session.delete :user_id 
  head :no_content
 end

end
```

React login page

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext';

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const { loggedIn, setLoggedIn, user, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate('');


  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('https://agile-reef-32463-2ad3559c3e00.herokuapp.com/login', {
        username,
        password
      }, { withCredentials: true }); // Include withCredentials option to send session cookie

      setLoggedIn(true);
      setUser(response.data);
      navigate('/');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />

        <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

and my AuthContext

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null); // Add user state

useEffect(() => {
const fetchUser = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://agile-reef-32463-2ad3559c3e00.herokuapp.com/me', {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    setUser(response.data);
    setLoggedIn(true);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching user:', error);
  }
};
    fetchUser();
  }, []);



  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, setLoggedIn, user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

The /me route is being logged when I first log in. My postman is also retrieving the data. However, when I refresh it resets everything. I'm sure the session is saved because cookies are being set, but it's not persisting.